# Using Vista under a Virtual Machine for testing apps

Tags: virtualization, virtual-pc

Does anyone know how to install a Vista UPGRADE edition to a virtual machine? Id like to use it for testing with older versions of .NET, but it wont let me install the upgrade version. I'd rather not have to install XP and then Upgrade it. Its a licensed legal copy with CD-Key and all. It just wont install to an empty VM because its an Upgrade version.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING: The following does violate your EULA**

Install Vista without using a serial number and choose the basic edition and also unselect auto activate.

After install, reinstall and now you can use your serial number and perform an upgrade.

See [Paul Thurrot's](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/winvista_upgrade_clean.asp) site for more in depth information.